# OpenCv doesn't accept multiple draw instructions in a function (in Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am following [this opencv tutorial about pose estimation and "augmented reality"](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html), and modifying it to work in real time with a webcam.  All works well but I found **this strange fact.**

I have to show some code first. 
The tutorial tells me to define an external draw function like

```
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img
```

to draw the 3 axes on my chessboard, then display it in my video with

```
  imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
  img = draw(img,corners,imgpts)
# Draw and display the corners
cv2.imshow('REALITY',img)
```

In this way, the script draws only the blue (X) line. 
But if I define 3 different functions like

```
def drawx(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    #img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    #img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img
```

leaving uncommented every time a different line, then draw the lines in sequence on the same image like this

```
    imgx = drawx(img,corners,imgpts)
    imgy = drawy(img,corners,imgpts)
    imgz = drawz(img,corners,imgpts)

# Draw and display the corners
cv2.imshow('REALITY',img)
```

I obtain the goal of the tutorial, [exactly like this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/pose_1.jpg), plus the fact I obtained a script to work in real time.

This is a workaround, but it works. 
My question is: **why openCV does not draw the three lines in the same function?**
It depends on my openCV version (2.4.8)? It depends on my python version (2.7)?

**UPDATE1**

After Micka's request (I hope to undertand it well) I modified my original draw function as

```
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    print imgpts
    return img
```

And the result (one set of points as example) is

```
[[[ 323.7434082   162.16279602]]

 [[ 329.28009033  350.18307495]]

 [[ 513.23809814  349.89364624]]

 [[ 512.85174561  161.18948364]]

 [[ 281.99362183  157.28944397]]

 [[ 290.17071533  384.95501709]]

 [[ 512.66680908  384.78421021]]

 [[ 512.18347168  156.10710144]]]
```

printing them in another way

```
print tuple(imgpts[0].ravel())
print tuple(imgpts[1].ravel())
print tuple(imgpts[2].ravel())
```

gives something like

```
(351.51596, 55.176319)
(352.62543, 254.72102)
(542.78979, 256.04565)
```

UPDATE 2
In the comments they suggest to print 3 "simple" lines in a function. I wrote

```
def draw_test(img):
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,10), (255,0,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,200), (0,255,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (10,200), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img
```

and surprisingly this time all the 3 lines were printed.

Comment: can you print all the point coordinates in your first draw function?

Comment: @Micka I update the question with 1 set of point coordinates found as input of the draw function. And I discovered that also if I put cv2.line in a FOR loop into the defined function, only the first line is drawn as well.

Comment: thx. but would be better to print each separately: tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()) tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()) tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()) to visualize the actual input. Next step would be to hard code 3 different lines in a single function for testing.

Comment: @Micka thank you for your help. I supposed that the original draw function can be considered as "3 different lines in a single function". Can you post (as a comment or an answer) an example of "hard coded function" for 3 different lines? I will update the question with the coordinates in a moment

Comment: sorry, dont know python syntax. Something like img = cv2.line(img, Point(0,0), Point (200,0)), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner,  Point(0,0), Point (200,200)), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, Point(0,0), Point (0,200)), (0,0,255), 5)

Comment: @marcoresk BTW, Is there some good reason why you're using a 3-year old version of OpenCV?  The 2.4.x branch is up to 13 now, so you're probably missing a good number of bugfixes.

Comment: @Micka In the Python API, points can be represented as tuples. So one option would be `img = cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,0), (255,0,0), 5)`

Comment: yes. if you do that, does it draw 3 lines in a single function?

Comment: @DanMašek I am forced not to use OpenCV 3 because I'm also working in a team that uses ROS for our robot (Indigo release) that have issues with 3.0 and later versions. I compiled 2.4.13 but ROS installation somehow changed this thing and I found myself to have 2.4.8. I'm still trying to figure out if updating OpenCV is safe for ROS or it will create a mess

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for the syntax. Drawing 3 different fixed lines in a single function seems not to be a problem. I'm more confused now, what is the problem if coordinates are well calculated?

Comment: @Micka I tried your suggestion and it seems that 3 different fixed lines in a function can be drawn. Any idea why is not possible to draw 2 or more different variable lines?

Comment: @marcoresk There's an important difference in the two functions. In one you have something like `img = cv2.line(img, ....`, in the other just `cv2.line(...`. According to [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line), this function returns `None`. So originally, you make your `img = None` after the first line, and the other two are drawn to nowhere.

Comment: can you try to first send your variable point tuples to new variables, then draw the lines from those variables and then print the variables, all in one function?

Comment: @DanMašek You give me the key of the solution. Thank you very much! I did not understand it because it was wrong even in the tutorial page. (I will write it). Maybe in 2.4.13 this thing becomes less critical?

Comment: @marcoresk I wrote up a more detailed answer. The version of the library won't make a difference on this one (as far as I know, maybe some time long ago the API was different).

Comment: @Micka Dan Masek give me the inspiration to understand what was the real problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: great, couldnt help there because I dont know opencv python syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest code that reproduces this problem and matches what you've got there is as follows.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img1 = np.zeros((300,300,3), np.uint8)
img2 = np.zeros((300,300,3), np.uint8)

def draw_1(img):
    img = cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,10), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,200), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, (0,0), (10,200), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

def draw_2(img):
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,10), (255,0,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (200,200), (0,255,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (0,0), (10,200), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

draw_1(img1)
draw_2(img2)

cv2.imwrite("lines_1.png", img1)
cv2.imwrite("lines_2.png", img2)
```

Lines 1:

[image: Bad result]

Lines 2:

[image: Good result]

Function `draw_1` here corresponds to your original `draw` function, and `draw_2` corresponds to what you had in UPDATE 2.

Notice that in `draw_1`, you assign the result of `cv2.line` back to `img`. This is a problem, since according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) `cv2.line` returns `None`.

Hence, your first call will turn your image to `None`, and the remaining two line are drawn to "Nothing".

Answer (score 1):

As [Dan Masek pointed out in his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694681/6564973) the original code from the tutorial

```
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img
```

has simply to be changed into

```
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img_x = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img_y = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img_z = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img_x, img_y, img_z
```

or without any specifications

```
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):

corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
return img
```

and all works.